Circle ω circumscribes square ABCD
Circle $\omega$ circumscribes square $ABCD$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Circle $\Gamma$ passes through $M$,$O$,$D$. If $AD$ meets $\Gamma$ at $P\not=D$, $\omega$ meets $\Gamma$ at $Q$, how to prove $PA=PQ$?
I cant really use Ptolemy so I tried proving $\angle PQA=\angle PAQ$, but the points are from 2 different circles so I cant even use circle theorems, I can get $\angle PQC$ from cos rule where C is the center of $\Gamma$ but reckon it wont be useful

Welcome to Math Stackexchange. Here we expect askers to pose good questions which provide context and show efforts. So what have you tried?

A user on Quora suggested this single line angle chase,
$\angle PAQ = 180° - \angle QAD = \angle DCQ = \angle DOQ / 2 = (180° - \angle QPD)/2 = (180° - \angle QPA)/2$
Then by angle sum $\angle PAQ=\angle PQA$ hence $PA=PQ$.

Since $OM\parallel PD$ and $OMPD$ is cyclic, $OMPD$ is also an isosceles trapezoid. Using symmetry and the fact that $OM$ is half of $AD$, we can deduce that $PA=MO$.
Since $\triangle DOQ$ is isosceles, we have $\stackrel{\large\frown}{DO}=\stackrel{\large\frown}{OQ}$. We get $\angle OPQ=\angle DPO=\angle POM$. Since $PQMO$ is cyclic, this angle condition tells us its also an isosceles trapezoid. It follows that $PQ=MO=PA$.
